# AFNetworking not send request but return response directly

Tags: ios, afnetworking, charles-proxy

I use AFNetworking(2.6.3). I try use Charles map local response for one request. After lot of times, when I disable this map, I also only get local response, can't get online response.

The response from AFNetworking:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17102e820> { URL: https://api.xiangrikui.com/bxr/apps/activities } { status code: 200, headers {
Connection = "Keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 604;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
"X-Charles-Map-Local" = "/Users/linliling/Desktop/???app?????/poster1.json";
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced something similar, but the connection said that it was closed. Try with another proxy program like [Burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/freedownload). It's not fancy as Charles but it gets the job done.

Also if you could post the response you see in Charles it will be useful to better understand the issue.

Comment: The response in Charles as same as <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17102e820>. The problem is AFNetworking not send request, when look in Charles. Maybe it return response from NSURLCache?

Comment: Maybe you could try disabling the cache system with

Comment: NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0
                                                        diskCapacity:0
                                                            diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

Comment: It's OK. But, this can not be reproduced when disable map local in charles, why?